# Unable to load class 'org.gradle.api.internal.component.Usage'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

after upgrading to the latest stable version of Android Studio with Gradle 4.2, I'm unable to do my projects or anything, and still having these issues. Even tho I've created a new project, and couldn't do it.

Any suggestions?

> Error:Unable to load class 'org.gradle.api.internal.component.Usage'

Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then kill all Java processes.

My gradle's build:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-    core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation project(':libs:searchview')
implementation project(':libs:AndroidImageSlider')

implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

implementation 'com.github.stfalcon:frescoimageviewer:0.5.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.1.2'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'

implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2'
implementation ('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io'
}
implementation ('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit-converters:2.0.2'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io'
}
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

implementation 'com.klinkerapps:drag-dismiss-activity:1.5.0'

implementation 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.2.0'

implementation 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1'
implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:1.1.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.8.0'

implementation('com.sangcomz:FishBun:0.7.7@aar') {
    transitive = true
}

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Thanks, I have solved this problem! This problem appears because the gradle I used 's version is `3.4.1`, and it is not compatible with the plugin `'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.4.0'` 's gradle version, when I upgrade it to `0.5.0`, it works.The answer is helping me solve that problem! Wish can help you!

Comment: Right now latest novoda version is 0.8.0 . I fixed my gradle with  classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.8.0' Hope this can help others too. :)

Comment: Wow this one had me puzzled. Thanks so much

Comment: The latest available version can be found in here: https://bintray.com/novoda/maven/bintray-release

Comment: Thanks, It helped to solve that issue that took so much time.