# I am getting build error while building the project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-service

Unable to load class 'org.gradle.api.services.BuildService'.

This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47863537/9423249 Might be this answer is useful for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Answers. So basically it was happening because of a module change. I solved it by removing kotlin and adding it again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi @Ehsan Abid can you clarify your steps better, i have the same error and unable to fix it.